# Why tf.gradient with tf.where returns None?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to do change input or/and output according to some condition. But the grad is None.

How can I get the gradient and keep the selection like the code below?

```py
input1, input2 = ..., ...
output1, output2 = model(input1), model(input2)

input = tf.where(tf.less(output1, output2), input1, input2)
output = tf.where(tf.less(output1, output2), output1, output2)

grad, = tf.gradient(output, input)
```

I print the type of input and output, their dimensions are the same as input1/output1(input2/output2). And if I only compute tf.gradient(output1,input1), it is no problem. What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```
input1, input2 = ..., ...
output1, output2 = model(input1), model(input2)
mask = tf.less(output1, output2)
input = tf.where(mask, input1, input2)
output = tf.where(mask, output1, output2)
grad = tf.add(*tf.gradients(output, [input1, input2]))
```

`tf.gradient` will return two tensors with zeros on the places where the corresponding input has not been selected. Hence, `grad` will hold the correct aggregated gradient for `input`.

Your original approach does not work because, from the point of view of TensorFlow, there is no dependency between `input` and `output`. `input` is computed from `input1` and `input2` and `output` is also computed from `input1` and `input2`, but there is no path in the graph from `input` to `output`, so there is no gradient.

Comment: Thanks for such a clear answer! But after I add `grad = tf.add(*tf.gradients(output, [input1, input2]))`, it says `ValueError: Tried to convert 'y' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported.`. Then I print `tf.gradients(output, [input1, input2])` and I find one of them is None. What may be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: @hjw That's strange, I tested the code above with a trivial `model` function (like a polynomial) and it worked. It could be that you have some non-differentiable function in `model`, but it would be strange that it works with `input1` but not `input2`. In any case, I'm afraid the issue must have to do with the definition of `model`.

Comment: The `model` function is a trivial neural network. I freeze the weights and loop `model(input1), model(input11), model(input111)....` several times. More specifically, input1/output1 stand for the input image and its logits, while input2 and output2 are the optimal I select from the history (select pairwise). Is it the heart of the matter?

Comment: @hjw Mmm I don't know really, can you check if the above snippet works for you if you define `model` with something trivial? E.g. `model = lambda x: 3 * x ** 2 -2 * x + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

in case someone is still stuck with NaN inputs, tf.where can be entirely replaced with:

```py
tf.minimum(tensor_having_nans, value_that_replaces_nans)
```

Also, `tf.maximum` works, and gradients don't truncate.
In case of 'inf', only `tf.minimum` works